# How can I make a recursive function in Python return a value instead of None?

Tags: python

I have this function that should return 1 once the input is 'x'. Why does this return None if the first input is 'y' and then the next input is 'x'?

```
def func():
    a = input('x or y\n')
    if a == 'x':
        return 1
    else:
        func()

print(func())
```

This is written in the command line:

```
x or y 
y         # My input
x or y
x         # My input 
None
```

Why does it return None and not 1?

Comment: write ``return func()`` in the ``else`` block. as for the "why" - every function in Python has a return value. If you do not set it explicitely, it will be ``None``.

Comment: @MikeScotty- In Python 3.6, his/her code is working fine without `return` in else block.

Comment: @shaikmoeed did you try exactly as OP posted? First enter ``y`` and then ``x``? Or did you enter ``x`` on the first go?

Comment: @MikeScotty- Ok, got it. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

functions always give output next to the return statement. You need to return your function as output for recursion.

```
def func():
    a = input('x or y\n')
    if a == 'x':
        return 1
    else:
        return func()

print(func())
```

will make your function recursive. Best regards...

Answer (score 0):

In the else statement you are calling the function but not returning from it.
So the function returns none if it goes in the else statement.

```
def func():
a = input('x or y\n')
if a == 'x':
    return 1
else:
    return func()

print(func())
```

Writing it like this will fix the problem as you'll return the calculated value from `func`. And the function will always return something regardless of the input.